# Conditional substitution of zero for one and one for zero

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a dataset where I need to change the value zero for one and one for zero in one column, depending on another column.

For example:

```
structure(list(id = c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2010, 2010), var = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Making changes for 2008 and 2010 only:

```
structure(list(id = c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2010, 2010), var = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help will be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is binary (1s and 0s), then `1 - x` switches the 1s and 0s. So we use `1 - x` for the rows you want to change:

```
rows = df$id %in% c(2008, 2010)
df$var[rows] = 1 - df$var[rows]
df
#      id var
# 1  2007   0
# 2  2007   1
# 3  2007   0
# 4  2008   1
# 5  2008   0
# 6  2008   0
# 7  2009   1
# 8  2009   0
# 9  2009   1
# 10 2010   1
# 11 2010   1
```

Comment: Excellent @Gregor Thomas, very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of a hack but just take the absolute value of `var` minus 1

```
a <- structure(list(id = c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2010, 2010), var = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

a$var <- abs(a$var-1)
```

Comment: If you just want to change certain rows you could use bracket notation `a$var[a$id==2008|a$id==2010] <- abs(a$var[a$id==2008|a$id==2010]-1)`